# Angular 4 Tree shaking with custom Material theme

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

I'm trying to do Tree shaking using rollup plugin after I do an AOT build.
I get no errors during this.

Then I serve `index.html` and `build.js` using `lite-server`

When I open the site only HTML is rendered no styles at all. XHR request are working also but there are no styles. Not Material nor my custom styles.

I'm using a custom Material Theme

At the console I get this warning:

**Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected. For more info refer to the theming guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming**

`.angular-cli.json`

```
"styles": [
      "./src/styles/styles.scss"
    ],
```

`src/styles/styles.scss`

```
//
// Material init structure
//
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();
// Define the palettes for your theme using the Material Design palettes available in palette.scss
// (imported above). For each palette, you can optionally specify a default, lighter, and darker
// hue.
$gt-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-light-blue, 900);
$gt-app-accent: mat-palette($mat-light-blue, 700);
// The warn palette is optional (defaults to red).
$gt-app-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);
// Create the theme object (a Sass map containing all of the palettes).
$gt-app-theme: mat-light-theme($gt-app-primary, $gt-app-accent, $gt-app-warn);
// Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app.
// Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each component
// that you are using.
@include angular-material-theme($gt-app-theme);
//
// Base Structure
//
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Roboto;
}

:focus {outline:none;}

//
// Base page general layout and styling
//
@mixin gt-tab-group-theme($theme) {
  $primary: map-get($theme, accent);
  .mat-tab-labels {
    background: mat-color($primary);
  }
  .mat-tab-label {
    flex-grow: 1;
    color: white;
  }
  .mat-ink-bar {
    background-color: white;
  }
}

.page {
  &-header-tabs {
    @include gt-tab-group-theme($gt-app-theme);
  }
  &-content {
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 2rem 2rem 4rem 2rem;
  }
}

//
// Basic Grid
//
.grid {
  display: flex;
  .item {
    &-grow {
      flex-grow: 1;
    }
  }
}

//
// Filter Container
//
.filter-container {
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1em 0;
  button:first-of-type {
    min-width: 135px;
  }
}

.search {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  md-icon {
    padding-top: 14px;
  }
  md-input-container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 350px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure, that the app finds your `styles.scss`? In my `.angular-cli.json` I defined `"styles": ["styles.scss"]` and `"root": "src"`. Your `styles.scss` looks ok for me.

Comment: yes, i have a `styles/styles.scss` and i'm pointing to it correctly. When I inspect the `bundle.js` the CSS is there but for some reason its not being rendered in the DOM

Comment: Did you inspect the bundle in the browser or in a file system? Just thinking if `ctrl+f5` might help due to browser cache.